# template warnings and error help, (gcc)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, warnings

I'm working on an container class template (for int,bool,strings etc), and I've been stuck with this error

```
cont.h:56: error: expected initializer before '&' token
```

for this section

```
template <typename T>
const Container & Container<T>::operator=(const Container<T> & rightCont){
```

what exactly have I done wrong there?.

Also not sure what this warning message means.

```
cont.h:13: warning: friend declaration `bool operator==(const Container<T>&, const Container<T>&)' declares a non-template function
cont.h:13: warning: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) -Wno-non-template-friend disables this warning
```

at this position

```
template <typename T>
class Container{
    friend bool operator==(const Container<T> &rhs,const Container<T> &lhs);
public:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you've done things backwards. When you specify the return type, you have to include the template parameter list into the template identifier (`Container<T>`), but when you specify parameter type, you don't need to do it (just `Container` is enough)

```
template <typename T>
const Container<T> & Container<T>::operator=(const Container & rightCont){
   ...
```

You did it the other way around for some reason.

In the second case, when you declare `operator ==` as a friend it simply warns you that that in this case `operator ==` you are referring to is an ordinary function. It can't be a specialization of a template. I.e. for the class `Container<int>` the function

```
bool operator==(const Container<int> &rhs, const Container<int> &lhs) {
  // ...
}
```

will be a friend. But specialization of function template

```
template <class U> 
bool operator==(const Container<U> &rhs, const Container<U> &lhs) {
  // ...
}
```

for `U == int` will *not* be a friend of `Container<int>`. If that's your intent, you are OK.

If you wanted to befriend a *specific* specialization of the above template, you'd have to say

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
  friend bool operator==<T>(const Container<T> &rhs, const Container<T> &lhs);
  ...
```

If you wanted to befriend *all* specialization of the above template, you'd have to say

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
  template <class U> 
  friend bool operator==(const Container<U> &rhs, const Container<U> &lhs);
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you're saying just `Container` the first time instead of `Container<T>`.

In the second case, I think you need to repeat the `template`: while member functions of a template class are implicitly templated, friend functions aren't necessarily, so it's necessary to be more explicitly .  I'm not sure what exact syntax you need for that purpose, but I think it is:

- before the class, `template<typename T> bool operator==(` etc
- in the class, `bool operator==<>(` etc

I think that's what the error message is trying to convey, though not super-clearly.